# using replace more efficiently in R

Tags: r, replace

I'm coding in R, and I want to replace all the values within a given vector which are over 0.5 with 1, and any value which is under 0.5 with -1. I know how to do this with two sequential calls to "replace" such as:

```
my_nums <- c(0.2,0.8,0.3,0.4)
my_nums_adj_temp <- replace(my_nums,my_nums>0.5,1)
my_nums_adj <- replace(my_nums_adj_temp,my_nums<0.5,-1)
```

And so "my_nums" goes from

```
> my_nums
[1] 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.4
```

to

```
> my_nums_adj
[1] -1  1 -1 -1
```

But is there a way to do this with just a single call to "replace"?

Comment: `ifelse(my_nums < 0.5, -1, 1)`? I don't think you can use a single call to `replace` here without some other trickery: `replace` is designed to replace values based on one conditional, and you have two target values with different (albeit complementing) conditionals.

Comment: or: `1 - 2*(ny_nums < .5)` (though the edge case of `my_nums == .5` is still ignored)

Comment: BTW: there is one "logical" flaw in your conditions that is being hidden by [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f): you are conditioning on numbers both above and below 0.5, but it is not clear what you want 0.5 to change to. It is unlikely to remain based on the FAQ (a known computer-science "artifact" from floating point equality), but it is certainly *feasible* that you would end up with three values in your output. Consider using `>=` or `<=` in one of your calls to `replace` ... it is at least explicit/clear.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the same value as the code in the question; however, if you really wanted to return 0 for an input component if that input is .5 (rather than returning .5 which is what the code in the question returns) then omit the second term or if you wanted to return some other value in that case replace the second .5 with that value.

```
sign(my_nums - .5) + .5 * (my_nums == .5)
## [1] -1  1 -1 -1
```

If you wanted to return 1 if the input is greater than or equal to .5 and -1 if it is less than we could use this.  For each component of the input, only one of the two terms can be non-zero so the result will be 1 or -1 for each component.

```
(my_nums >= .5) - (my_nums < .5)
```

Comment: Great thank you .... I realize I didn't deal with the 0.5 case in the code I provided but that was just an oversight. I was just trying to create a simple example of my question.